Редактирование векторных изображений в Adroid Studio
Есть векторное изображение в формате xml. Есть ли какие-либо инструменты, которые могут предварительно редактировать некоторые из path, изменив цвет в свойстве android:fillColor и отправить в ImageView?

UPD: написал CustomView, которое принимает эти path, парсит и рисует на canvas. Останется только решить вопрос с производительностью

Только целиком для всего вектора.
